# The constructor BeepManager(Activity) is not visible

Tags: java, android

I have imported zxing lib **com.google/com.google.zxing.client.android.captureactivity.jar.zip( 497 k)** into my project.
Then I have a imporgted BeepManager class in my project this way:

```
import com.google.zxing.client.android.BeepManager;
private BeepManager beepManager;
beepManager = new BeepManager(activity);
```

After the import statement, I have this error prompt:

```
The constructor BeepManager(Activity) is not visible
```

EDITED:

```
DecodeHandler(CaptureActivity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
        baseApi = activity.getBaseApi();
        beepManager = new BeepManager(CaptureActivity.this);
        beepManager.updatePrefs();
```

Please what could be wrong...

Comment: Are you trying to use it in the same activity you pass as a parameter?

Comment: try this 'beepManager = new BeepManager(getApplicationContext);' may be help you

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this:

```
beepManager = new BeepManager(activity);
```

To this:

```
beepManager = new BeepManager(<ActivityName>.this);
```

EDIT: The problem is occuring because you are sending Class identifier over an instance of Class, you can solve it changing this:

```
DecodeHandler(CaptureActivity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
        baseApi = activity.getBaseApi();
        beepManager = new BeepManager(CaptureActivity.this);
        beepManager.updatePrefs();
```

to

```
DecodeHandler(CaptureActivity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
        baseApi = activity.getBaseApi();
        beepManager = new BeepManager(activity);
        beepManager.updatePrefs();
```

Comment: Please check edited on my question to reflect your answer, but the problem is still there.

Comment: The constructor BeepManager(Activity) is not visible.

Comment: Its a library. This is the url of the download. http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/c/Downloadcomgooglezxingclientandroidcaptureactivityjar.htm

Comment: Oh okay, my bad, I'll check it up.

Comment: activity cannot be resolved to a type.     The error prompt after the edit

Comment: Do you mind if I send you the complete source code. So that you can help me look at it

Comment: If you can you should post it on your question so anyone in the website might help you.